# Checking C# class value null, whitespace, empty, length otherwise return 'unknown'

Tags: c#, class

I know there are a 100 ways of doing things in C#. However I was wondering if i could get some help on knowing what is a good way to testing a value. In my example i have a property called 'Directory' in my class which i want to set the property value to 'Unknown' if any of the following are true

- is null
- is empty
- is whitespace
- is length == 0

**Pseudo code...**

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(s);

s.Length == 0;

String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
```

I've commented in my code what im trying to do. You guys may have a better solution.

**My Class**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;

namespace Varo.Model
{
    public class DirectoryNode
    {
        public DirectoryNode(string filepath, INode parent)
        {
            // if filepath is empty || null || whitespace or || length.0
            // then set to 'Unknown' prior to creating the Directory info.
            this.File = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
        }

        public DirectoryInfo File { get; private set; }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.File == null ? string.Empty : this.File.Name; }
        }

        public string Path
        {
            get { return this.File == null ? string.Empty : this.File.FullName; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not one right answer - each has a different purpose, thus the existence of different methods.  `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` encapsulates all of them, so if that's what you are wanting to check for then use that.

Comment: Look at IsNullOrWhiteSpace code - this is what you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) does all at once.

```
public string Directory
{
    get { 
        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SomeString) ? "unknown" : this.SomeString; 
    }
}
```